# How to execute a micropython program in Raspbian OS?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, micropython

I have a general understanding of microcontrollers and embedded systems but I am completely new to Raspberry pi. I have a task that requires fairly fast GPIO operations, so from the research I made, Micropython could bring more benefits than regular Python.

I wrote a sub-10 line led blink program in micropython, for learning and experimenting (put a .mpy extension to it) but I'm facing a problem on what to do next, how to execute it?

```
import machine
led = machine.Pin(21,machine.Pin.OUT)
while True:
    led.high()
    led.low()
```

As far as I found out, you cannot just write "python3 ledblink.py" in your Raspberry Pi terminal as you would for regular Python scripts. I tried to google it for quite some time, but everything I find is either ESP's or Pico's micropython tutorials. I need a detailed guide from textfile to execution on how to run the micropython file on Raspberry pi terminal (I am running a 3B+ model). I have installed my micropython following this guide: https://snapcraft.io/install/micropython/raspbian

Comment: If you need tight timing and fast GPIO operations, a Raspberry Pi (a real computer that runs Linux, a non-real-time OS) might not be what you want.

Comment: (Also, I don't think the UNIX port of Micropython would have GPIO capabilities out of the box...)

Comment: Do not be distracted by the idea of my project, the main topic about micropython still persists

Comment: Well, once you've installed `micropython`, I'd assume it to be available as `micropython`. Could you add your `ledblink.mpy` in your question too?

Comment: Sure, my code is dead simple for now (I am testing the speed for GPIO writing, later on I might add some assembler commands to speeds things up, but do not focus on that)

I am not sure if I understood you right, but you are saying that I should be able to run the code by typing "micropython ledblink.mpy" into my terminal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure running `micropython ledblink.mpy` would get you somewhere. Probably an error message, but that'd be progress.

Comment: But again, I really don't think you'll get far with trying to run Micropython on a regular Raspberry Pi. On that platform, you'd probably want to use regular Python and the `RPi.GPIO` library that Raspbian installs by default, or if you want to see how fast you can actually write to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins, you'd write that in C and run it.

Comment: My error log looks like that: 
vilius@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/Script $ micropython mGPIO.mpy
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Pin'` – yep, as I assumed in my 2nd comment, the UNIX port of Micropython doesn't know about Pins (since no generic UNIX machine has "pins", and it's not a Raspberry Pi port).

Comment: Ok, I will also consider C, but is there any solution to my micropython quest? It was not only the code problem, but the error log gave me another error, I am not even sure what is the cause of it...

Comment: as @AKX said, a Raspberry PI with Raspbian is NOT a microcontroller.  it's got a whole (Linux based) operating system on it.  micropython is for embedded devices (like microcontrollers) and it effectively functions as the "OS" of the device.  you're trying to use the wrong tool for the job, just use the normal Python that's included in the OS with the appropriate packages

Comment: @ViliusŽalėnas As I said, you can use the regular (non-Micro) Python for Raspbian and drive the GPIO pins with it first. [That `libarmmem` warning is apparently a known issue for that Micropython build.](https://github.com/hjiawei/micropython-snap/issues/2)

Comment: How fast is 'fairly fast'?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments: MicroPython is for microcontrollers, not for real Linux machines such as your Raspberry Pi 3+. It does have an UNIX port (which you've installed), which is useful for trying some things out, but it crucially does not have GPIO pin support, since it's just a generic UNIX port (and not all generic UNIX machines would have GPIO pins).

However, your Raspbian ships with regular Python, and the [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) library.

This should be approximately equivalent to your MicroPython code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
try:
    while True:
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

You can put that in a file and run it with `python3 something.py`.

As discussed, if your goal is to test the GPIO speed, then you'd use e.g. [pigpio](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) and C code.